# MySql query execution time

Tags: mysql, time, mysql-workbench, execution

I am using MySQL Workbench on Windows. How do I find out the time taken to execute a query like

```
Select * from employers where employerid > 200
```

Is there a statement I can enter that returns the execution time for this query?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql execution time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631316/mysql-execution-time)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, but the link provided is broken, and I not know how to use the profiler with MySQL workbench.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

MySQL workbench is the way to go for things like this (optimization, benchmarking of queries, etc.).  You say you're not familiar with it, so I'd recommend reading a tutorial from the good folks at [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-getting-started-tutorial.html)