# How to get the amount of time a query will take in php?

Tags: php

I am getting result from database and I want to print the amount of seconds or minute it took to bring me the result.

something like this:

```
if($fba_num_rows > 0){
//print the amount of time the query took
//like "Search completed in 0.57 seconds"

}
```

How do i do this? please help.

Comment: save the time before and after the query runs, then compare them afterwards.

Comment: Look at this answer pls
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1631335/5094931

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`microtime`](http://php.net/microtime) function:

```
if($fba_num_rows > 0){
    $time_start = microtime(true);
    // your code

    $time_end = microtime(true);
    echo 'Search completed in ' . ($time_end - $time_start) . ' seconds';
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much..looks simple

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the microtime function as said in the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php).

Like:

```
$start_time = microtime(true);
// Do DB Ops
if($fba_num_rows > 0){
    // Find the end time
    $end_time = microtime(true);
    // Calculate the time taken
    $time_taken = $end_time - $start_time;
    // Print the time
    printf("Query took %f seconds", $time_taken);
}
```

Hope it helps!