# Execution time of multiple requests (100+)

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlperformance

I'm looking for the time of execution of a pack of 552 SQL requests on MySQL. I want one execution time for the 552 requests (or the sum of 552 execution times). Ideally, what I need is an SQL requests based way to do it. My MySQL version is 5.7.

I've done a lot of research (maybe not in a good way because what I found is not that relevant, although it seems to be a common question).
I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631316/mysql-execution-time) but you can measure only 100 queries max (15 by default). Although I can approach the result by doing:

```sql
SELECT SUM(Duration)*5.52 as execTime 
FROM information_schema.profiling
```

However, I can't change the default query allowed number from "15" to "100" anyway. When I try:

`SET profiling_history_size = 100`

- mysql console returns `Query OK, 0 row affected, 1 warning`
- phpMyAdmin returns `Table 'performance_schema.session_variables' doesn't exists`. Note that I've a `performance_schema` sub-folder in my mysql/data folder but no `session_variables.frm` file in it.

I would like to know:

- if there is a way to bypass the 100 queries limit? (even if the method is different)
- If not, how to change the `profiling_history_size` value?

Comment: Perhaps you can try ```SET @@profiling = 0;
SET @@profiling_history_size = 0;
SET @@profiling_history_size = 100; 
SET @@profiling = 1;```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't work (still 15 rows in the `SHOW PROFILES` result